# Displaying posts of users the user follows through Laravel relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I would like to display the posts of everyone the current user follows, ordered by date desc.

I have a many to many relationship supplying all the people the user is following.

```
$users = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->follow()->get();
```

I have a one to many relationship displaying the posts for any user.

```
$updates = App\User::find(?????)->updates()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

The question mark's shows where the followers ID's need to be placed.

I can put the above query inside the for each loop but that obviously works its way through each follower rather than all posts in date order.

I suspect I may need to set a new relationship and work from the beginning. Can anyone advise.

**User Model**

```
     public function updates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\update');
    }

/**
 * User following relationship
 */
 // Get all users we are following
public function follow()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_follows', 'user_id', 'follow_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('id');;;
}
// This function allows us to get a list of users following us
public function followers()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_follows', 'follow_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();;
}

}
```

**Update Model**

```
public function user_update()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the posts, it is probably going to be easier starting a query on the `Post` model, and then filter the posts based on their relationships.

Assuming your `Post` model has an `author` relationship to the `User` that created the post, and the `User` has a `follower` relationship to all the `User`s that are following it, you could do:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$posts = \App\Post::whereHas('author.follower', function ($q) use ($userId) {
        return $q->where('id', $userId);
    })
    ->latest() // built in helper method for orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Now, `$posts` will be a collection of your Post models that were authored by a user that is being followed by your authenticated user.

Comment: Thank you, I should clear a few bits up the posts model is called updates, I can adjust the above to suit that. I have added the relationships to the above are they all okay? @patricus

Comment: @JamesParsons The `belongsTo` side of the relationship builds the foreign key based on the relationship method name. Since your method is named `user_update()`, it will look for the field `user_update_id`. If this field name is correct, then it all looks fine. If not, you either need to rename your relationship method or pass in the foreign key field name as the second parameter. Other than that, looks fine.

Comment: Could you just confirm would I would need to change in your answer? I cant see where `author.follower` fits

Comment: I have run the following code from within the controller

Comment: @JamesParsons Oh, gotcha. You would need to change "author.follower" to "user_update.followers". You can read more about querying relationships in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

Comment: I have learnt a lot about relationships from the docs, I just cant get my head around the more complicated ones at the moment. I have an error...

`ErrorException in update.php line 13:
Declaration of App\update::update() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update(array $attributes = Array, array $options = Array)`

Comment: @JamesParsons The `Model` already has a method called `update()`. It is used to update the record in the database. You cannot create a relationship method named `update()`, because that will try to override the `update()` method from the inherited `Model` class.

Comment: Fixed that I seem to be getting a slightly different problem:
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous ` Are there too many queries to the id column? How would I fix it?

Comment: @JamesParsons Change `get()` to `toSql()`. This will return the query being generated, without running it. Post the query being run here.

Comment: Thanks for everything! `"select * from `updates` where exists (select * from `users` where `updates`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and exists (select * from `users` as `laravel_reserved_0` inner join `user_follows` on `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `user_follows`.`user_id` where `user_follows`.`follow_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` = ?)) order by `created_at` desc"`

Comment: @JamesParsons Yeah, the self-related belongsToMany relationship makes it a little more confusing. I'd try changing `'id'` to `'user_follows.user_id'` in the where clause.